# ESP8266 proper power circuit for avoid reset issue

Tags: esp8266, power

I am using an ESP8266 in a project which will be on for at least 18 hours a day. I'm using an Arduino 3.3V power supply to feed the ESP8266.

The issue I'm facing is a reset issue. It sometimes disconnects from the hotspot automatically.  I have heard this could be because the ESP8266 draws more power than the Arduino's regulator is able to supply.

I want to know what will be the proper circuit to power the ESP8266.

I know I have to use an AMS1117 regulator, but I also know I have to use capacitors too. How would I configure the AMS1117 with capacitors to properly power an ESP8266?

Comment: A simpler solution for those who don't want to deal with wiring up a regulator is to get the "nodemcu" style of ESP8266 module having its own regulator.  These typically also have a USB serial interface, though determine which chip is used and its driver situation on your computer's operating system before purchasing one.

Comment: The ESP8266 power problem keeps coming up, so we need a canonical question to close the re-asks as duplicates against.  I think post-edits this could be a candidate, but perhaps there are other choices.

Answer (score 3):

You don't "need" an AMS1117 regulator. You *need a power source that can supply enough current.*  One *example* is an AMS1117-33, although it's not a great one as far as efficiency goes (though it is simple).

The basic circuit is to have a 10µF capacitor on both the input and output of the regulator - that should be enough for most uses.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCCvhu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Powered from more than around 5V the AMS1117-33 would need some heatsinking.  You can also add some smaller (100nF) capacitors in parallel with the 10µF ones if you want to improve high frequency response.

[You can pick modules up with this circuit on from eBay for a dollar.](http://www.ebay.co.uk/sch/i.html?_nkw=3.3v+dc-dc+1117)

A better power source would be a "buck" switching regulator. These are far more efficient and generate much less heat.  It's harder to search for these on eBay since all the AMS1117-33 modules seem to be labelled erroneously as "buck" regulators (which they so are not!), so be careful when looking around. A true "buck" regulator will have an inductor on it. [Here's one example](http://www.ebay.com/itm/152551807267).

Comment: Add " -ams1117" to your search query in eBay, to remove listings that has AMS1117 in the title.

Comment: @Gerben I did - that's how I got the example one I listed. Still not foolproof though.

Comment: The spec says that an AMS1117-3.3 can deliver 1A, but realistically that only works if you run it off 5V. The ESP draws ~400mA when it is transmitting, and at 12V the AMS is dissipating 8.7V x 0.4A =  3.48W. That makes it kinda hot, and it tends to cut out.  A buck regulator, even a tiny one using MP2307, is a much better bet. **set the voltage first** before connecting to the ESP!

Comment: ESP8266 draws ~170mA when transmitting