# Can upload programs to ESP8266 with Arduino Nano but not run them

Tags: arduino-ide, esp8266, arduino-nano, wireless

I am trying to use my Arduino Nano to program my Generic ESP-01 Module. I want to use the module to control an RGB LED Light Strip but am not having much success, only errors....

These are my connections:

Esp-01 -------------------------------------------------- Arduino Nano

TX <------------------------------------------------------> TX

RX <-----------------------------------------------------> RX

VCC <----------------------------------------------------> 3.3v

CH_PD <------------------------------------------------> 3.3v

GND <---------------------------------------------------> GND

[image: My Connections]

I have also grounded my reset pin on my Arduino and when programming I ground the GPIO0 on the ESP-01 to enter flash mode. Not too sure if this would cause a problem but just wanted to note that my Arduino Nano is a clone and runs on the CH340G USB drivers not FTDI. It successfully uploads the program with the Arduino IDE but not much after that. I have also tried uploading the Blink program and the CheckFlashConfig program but the same error on startup.

Here is the error:

```
ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:2, boot mode:(3,6)

load 0x4010f000, len 1384, room 16 
tail 8
chksum 0x2d
csum 0x2d
v09f0c112
~ld
```

I also decoded the stack that I sometimes get with ESP Exception Decoder:

```
0x40104bcd: wdt_feed at ?? line ?
0x40104bca: wdt_feed at ?? line ?
0x402177a8: user_uart_wait_tx_fifo_empty at ?? line ?
0x40104bd3: wdt_feed at ?? line ?
0x40104bb4: wdt_feed at ?? line ?
0x40104bcd: wdt_feed at ?? line ?
0x40104bca: wdt_feed at ?? line ?
0x402177a8: user_uart_wait_tx_fifo_empty at ?? line ?
0x40104bd3: wdt_feed at ?? line ?
0x40104bb4: wdt_feed at ?? line ?
0x40104bcd: wdt_feed at ?? line ?
0x40104bca: wdt_feed at ?? line ?
0x402177a8: user_uart_wait_tx_fifo_empty at ?? line ?
0x40104bd3: wdt_feed at ?? line ?
0x40104bb4: wdt_feed at ?? line ?
0x40104bcd: wdt_feed at ?? line ?
0x40104bca: wdt_feed at ?? line ?
0x402177a8: user_uart_wait_tx_fifo_empty at ?? line ?
0x40104bd3: wdt_feed at ?? line ?
0x40104bb4: wdt_feed at ?? line ?
0x40104bcd: wdt_feed at ?? line ?
0x40104bca: wdt_feed at ?? line ?
0x402177a8: user_uart_wait_tx_fifo_empty at ?? line ?
0x40104bd3: wdt_feed at ?? line ?
0x40104bb4: wdt_feed at ?? line ?
0x40104bcd: wdt_feed at ?? line ?
0x40104bca: wdt_feed at ?? line ?
0x402177a8: user_uart_wait_tx_fifo_empty at ?? line ?
0x40104bd3: wdt_feed at ?? line ?
0x40104bb4: wdt_feed at ?? line ?
0x40104bcd: wdt_feed at ?? line ?
0x40104bca: wdt_feed at ?? line ?
0x402177a8: user_uart_wait_tx_fifo_empty at ?? line ?
0x40104bd3: wdt_feed at ?? line ?
0x40104bb4: wdt_feed at ?? line ?
0x40104bcd: wdt_feed at ?? line ?
0x40104bca: wdt_feed at ?? line ?
0x402177a8: user_uart_wait_tx_fifo_empty at ?? line ?
0x40104bd3: wdt_feed at ?? line ?
0x40104bb4: wdt_feed at ?? line ?
0x40104bcd: wdt_feed at ?? line ?
0x40104bca: wdt_feed at ?? line ?
0x402177a8: user_uart_wait_tx_fifo_empty at ?? line ?
0x40104bd3: wdt_feed at ?? line ?
0x40104bb4: wdt_feed at ?? line ?
0x40104bcd: wdt_feed at ?? line ?
0x40104bca: wdt_feed at ?? line ?
0x402177a8: user_uart_wait_tx_fifo_empty at ?? line ?
0x40104bd3: wdt_feed at ?? line ?
0x40104bb4: wdt_feed at ?? line ?
0x40104bcd: wdt_feed at ?? line ?
0x40104bca: wdt_feed at ?? line ?
0x4022bea0: cal_rf_ana_gain at ?? line ?
0x40228690: tx_cap_init at ?? line ?
0x4022d4cd: ram_rfcal_pwrctrl at ?? line ?
0x4022d37c: ram_rfcal_pwrctrl at ?? line ?
0x4022be18: cal_rf_ana_gain at ?? line ?
0x4022be3d: cal_rf_ana_gain at ?? line ?
0x4022be9c: cal_rf_ana_gain at ?? line ?
0x40228689: tx_cap_init at ?? line ?
0x40228690: tx_cap_init at ?? line ?
0x4022a600: chip_v6_initialize_bb at ?? line ?
0x40226237: phy_init at ?? line ?
0x40105eae: register_phy_ops at ?? line ?
0x4022b3b2: register_chipv6_phy at ?? line ?
0x4021a93e: wifi_station_set_default_hostname at ?? line ?
0x40201b39: __wrap_register_chipv6_phy at /Users/privitec/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.3.0/cores/esp8266/core_esp8266_phy.c line 261
0x4022f660: sleep_reset_analog_rtcreg_8266 at ?? line ?
0x4010564a: spi_flash_read at ?? line ?
0x402174c3: rijndaelKeySetupEnc at ?? line ?
0x40217b3c: user_uart_wait_tx_fifo_empty at ?? line ?
0x40217b17: user_uart_wait_tx_fifo_empty at ?? line ?
0x40104e90: wdt_feed at ?? line ?
```

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

**Update:**
I have tried reinstalling AT firmware version 0.9.2.2 with esptool. Again it successfully detects the ESP-01 and programs it. I still get the same error (sometimes instead of getting boot mode:(3,6) I get boot mode:(3,7)) when powering up and I have tried to input `AT` into the Serial Monitor and I get no response.

Comment: you need to go rx-tx, tx-rx...

Comment: Already tried... Still no luck.

Comment: I believe it has a program mode and a run mode (it has on some other ESP versions). You could Google around on that a little

Comment: I know that grounding GPIO0 puts it into flashing mode. I have also tried other combinations pulling other pins high and low but nothing has worked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ESP8266 proper power circuit for avoid reset issue](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/39242/esp8266-proper-power-circuit-for-avoid-reset-issue) in that until the **improper use** of the Arduino's 50 mA rated 3.3v regulator to power the ESP's up to ~170 mA current requirement is corrected, it's not worth considering anything else.

Comment: `you need to go rx-tx, tx-rx` Actually in this case the Nano is only being used as a USB-serial adapter to directly program the ESP8266 and so RX-RX, TX-TX is the correct wiring.

Comment: `I have tried to input AT into the Arduino IDE and I get no response.` When you upload to the ESP8266 via the Arduino IDE the AT firmware is overwritten. "input AT into the Arduino IDE" is a very imprecise statement. Do you mean the Serial Monitor? Please make a better effort with your questions, otherwise they will be closed.

Comment: Sorry, yes I mean the serial monitor and this is even after erasing the ESP-01 then flashing AT firmware back to it with esptool.

Comment: I'd also say putting 5V (TX) into a 3.3V (RX) such as ESP-*-s might not be the best idea. Please use a level converter. The opposite is okay as 3.3V is detected as HIGH on an Arduino.

Comment: I have tried using a voltage divider with a 1k resistor and a 2.2k resistor but it makes no difference.